# Can I wipe a Galaxy S4 Mini with dead screen and digitizer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I have here a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini (GT-I9195). It has met a terrible fate on a parking lot, and is damaged beyond repair: broken screen and digitizer, battery bent out of shape.

Apart from these terrible wounds, it appears to still be working fine: it boots and vibrates, the side and home buttons work fine, and USB access is operational. In particular, I was able to backup all that I wanted using MTP.

We are going to buy a replacement of course (though finding a good 4.3" phone is not easy nowadays). **My question is: can I wipe this phone? If yes, how?**

Obviously, anything involving reading or touching the screen is a no-go: that part is truly fully dead. I am hoping I can access and blindly use some kind of boot menu using only the side keys, or that I can somehow perform that over USB, or that I can press or short some internal reset switch inside the phone.

(Software would preferably be run from Linux, but Windows 7 or 10 is also possible.)

Comment: oh oh, _battery bent out of shape_, i'd hurry on this if i were you

Comment: Why'd you still want to wipe it? Break out the motherboard and break the chips like biscuits, no one will ever be able to recover _anything_ from them.

Comment: @MarkYisri you're right, this is the part that truly worries me.

Comment: @AndyYan Physical destruction is a possibility, but it is not that easy to do, nor that easy to recycle afterwards. I'd rather keep it as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the HardDrive Out Burn it

Also if Your google account is Connected:
1.Go to google.com Enter "Find My Phone
2.There should be a little Window with the last known location of your phone
3.There should also be 2 little buttons there a "Ring" and a "Recover"
4.Once you click on that all the way at the bottom there should be consider erasing your phone (The page where it should send you)
5.USe that and follow the instructions.
Good Lucj

Comment: There is no hard drive in the smartphone. But I understand you suggest physical destruction, and this is indeed a last-resort possibility. Thanks a lot for reminding me that I can wipe the phone from the Android Device Manager web interface.